# Performance Optimization

Tags: linux, scripting, performance

I have one script which roughly has to read 1.5 million lines and process the lines and print out output in cvs file. This script is current taking more than 8-9 hours to process 250 thousands lines. Is is possible to reduce time ?

```
    ###### Start Reading Line by Line When IMSI is available ##########################
    IFS=$'\n'     # new field separator, the end of line
    for line in `cat temp_req`
    do
    #printf "Line: "$line
    #printf "\n=============================================================================================\n"
    ### MSISDN , IMSI , Circle ID #####
    MSISDN=`echo $line | grep svc_result | sed -e 's,.*<msid type="MSISDN" enc="ASC">\([^<]*\)</msid>.*,\1,g' | grep -v xml`
    IMSI=`echo $line | grep svc_result | sed -e 's,.*<imsi>\([^<]*\)</imsi>.*,\1,g' | grep -v xml`
    ###### Check IMSI is Blank or Not #############
    if [ ! -z $IMSI ];then
    CIRCLE=`echo ${IMSI:0:5}`
    CIRCLE_NAME=`cat mapping | grep $CIRCLE | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
    ############## Getting Details By Circle One ######################################################
    if [ ! -z $CIRCLE ] && [ $CIRCLE = 40496 ]   ## HR If start
    then
    ### Check Request Status ###
    LAT=`echo $line | grep svc_result | sed -e 's,.*<X>\([^<]*\)</X>.*,\1,g' | grep -v xml`
    if [ "x$LAT" = "x"  ]
    then
    ### Get Error Status , Time , NDC, MSC, Additional Info ####
    TIME=`echo $line | grep -i svc_result | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'`
    ERROR_CODE=`echo $line | grep svc_result | awk -F '=' '{print $7}' | awk -F '>' '{print $1}' | tr  -s '"' ' ' | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
    ERROR_DESC=`echo $line | grep svc_result | awk -F '=' '{print $7}' | awk -F '>' '{print $2}' | awk -F'<' '{print $1}'`
    NDC=`echo $line | grep svc_result | sed -e 's,.*<ndc>\([^<]*\)</ndc>.*,\1,g' | grep -v xml`
    MSC_NO=`echo $line | grep svc_result | sed -e 's,.*<vmscno>\([^<]*\)</vmscno>.*,\1,g' | grep -v xml`
    ADD_INFO=`echo $line | grep svc_result | sed -e 's,.*<add_info>\([^<]*\)</add_info>.*,\1,g' | grep -v xml | awk -F';' '{print $2}'`
    ############## Validate MSC GT and ADD Info Parameter ##############
    if [ '91$MSC_NO' = '91' ];then 
    MSC_NO="0"
    fi
    if [ 'x$ADD_INFO' = 'x' ];then
    ADD_INFO=`echo $line | grep svc_result | sed -e 's,.*<add_info>\([^<]*\)</add_info>.*,\1,g' | grep -v xml | awk -F';' '{print $1}'`
    fi
    ################# Finished Validation #################
    ######################## Create Error Report ###########
    if [ ERROR$ERROR_CODE = ERROR1 ];then
    HR_ERROR1=`expr $HR_ERROR1 + 1`;HR_FAILED_COUNT=`expr $HR_FAILED_COUNT + 1`
    elif [ ERROR$ERROR_CODE = ERROR2 ];then
    HR_ERROR2=`expr $HR_ERROR2 + 1`;HR_FAILED_COUNT=`expr $HR_FAILED_COUNT + 1`
    elif [ ERROR$ERROR_CODE = ERROR3 ];then
    HR_ERROR3=`expr $HR_ERROR3 + 1`;HR_FAILED_COUNT=`expr $HR_FAILED_COUNT + 1`
    elif [ ERROR$ERROR_CODE = ERROR4 ];then
    HR_ERROR4=`expr $HR_ERROR4 + 1`;HR_FAILED_COUNT=`expr $HR_FAILED_COUNT + 1`
    elif [ ERROR$ERROR_CODE = ERROR5 ];then
    HR_ERROR5=`expr $HR_ERROR5 + 1`;HR_FAILED_COUNT=`expr $HR_FAILED_COUNT + 1`
    elif [ ERROR$ERROR_CODE = ERROR6 ];then
    HR_ERROR6=`expr $HR_ERROR6 + 1`;HR_FAILED_COUNT=`expr $HR_FAILED_COUNT + 1`
    elif [ ERROR$ERROR_CODE = ERROR202 ];then
    HR_ERROR202=`expr $HR_ERROR202 + 1`;HR_FAILED_COUNT=`expr $HR_FAILED_COUNT + 1`
    elif [ ERROR$ERROR_CODE = ERROR203 ];then
    HR_ERROR203=`expr $HR_ERROR203 + 1`;HR_FAILED_COUNT=`expr $HR_FAILED_COUNT + 1`
    elif [ ERROR$ERROR_CODE = ERROR501 ];then
    HR_ERROR501=`expr $HR_ERROR501 + 1`;HR_FAILED_COUNT=`expr $HR_FAILED_COUNT + 1`
    fi
    else
    #print $SUCCESS_COUNT
    HR_SUCCESS_COUNT=`expr $HR_SUCCESS_COUNT + 1`
    fi  
    fi
    done
```

Comment: re-write it in a more efficient language like perl, or python.

Comment: it seem that for every line of the file you are launching 20+ processes, converting some of that use use bash expansion will help if a full translation id deemed too hard.

Comment: Lots of identical `echo $line | grep svc_results` that could go into a temp variable. But all in all, yes, try any other language. The problem looks straightforward enough, you could do it in C in a day at most even if you don't know any C so far, but perl/python/ruby might give you enough of a boost.

Comment: Can python process 1.5 million lines in 2-3 hours ?

Comment: Or, if you’d rather keep it as a shell script, at least advance from Shell Scripting 101 to Shell Scripting 201. (1) Don’t use `\`…\``, use `$(…)`. (2) Don’t do `for line in \`cat temp_req\``. Try to rewrite it as a single `awk` script that processes the entire input file, rather than ten little `awk` scripts that handle snippets. But, if you really *really **really*** must have a shell script process each line, use `IFS= read -r line` / `do` / … / `done < temp_req`. (3)  Don’t do `CIRCLE=\`echo ${IMSI:0:5}\``; do `CIRCLE=${IMSI:0:5}`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Don’t do `cat mapping | grep $CIRCLE`, do `grep "$CIRCLE" mapping`.  (4a) Don’t `cat` a single file unless the output is directly to the screen, or in a few other cases.  Don’t `cat` a single file and pipe it into something.  Google UUOC.  (4b) You should always quote all references to shell variables unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. (5) Don’t pipe `grep` into `awk`; `awk` can do the line selection itself. (6) Indent properly. (7) Try to avoid lines that are so long that they don’t fit on the screen.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (8) Look at the PARAMETER EXPANSION section of bash(1) to see ways to manipulate strings without having to use `sed` or `awk` every time.  (9) `[ '91$MSC_NO' = '91' ]` and `[ 'x$ADD_INFO' = 'x' ]` will never be true.  What do you think you are testing?  (10) Use bash’s builtin arithmetic rather than `expr`.  (11) Reexamine you script logic to see whether you really need to have `HR_FAILED_COUNT=\`expr $HR_FAILED_COUNT + 1\`` nine times.  (12) Look into arrays, index variables, and `case` statements.